# Java: Casting long to int

Tags: java, int, long-integer

Let's assume the variables `start` and `stop` are both long-type variables.

```
int diff = (int) start-stop;
```

This code yields the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int`, while

```
int diff = (int) (start-stop);
```

runs as expected. Why?

Comment: in the second case you cast the result of (start-stop) first case to start

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7

Answer (score 3):

Because in the first, the `(int)` applies to `start`, not the expression, like this:

```
int diff = ((int) start) - stop; // <== Your first expression clarified
```

Then you subtract a `long` from the resulting `int`, and the result of that expression is a `long`. (If it *had* worked, it probably would have had the side-effect of giving you an incorrect result, if `start` ever has values that are too big to store in an `int`.)

By first doing the subtraction and getting the `long` result, *then* casting that to `int`, you can store it in your `int` variable. (Presumably you know it'll fit from your application logic.)

Answer (score 1):

Because Java doesn't allow *implicit* narrowing conversions.  One would be required in the first case, as it's equivalent to:

```
int diff = ((long)(int)start) - stop;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int diff = (int) start - stop;
```

is equal to

```
int diff = (int) (long) start - (long) stop; // we substract long types
```

can be simplified to

```
int diff = (int) start - (long) stop; // (int)(long) x means (int) x
```

is equal to

```
int diff = ((int) start) - (long) stop; // casting is applied only to start
```

is equal to

```
int diff = ((long)(int) start) - (long) stop; // compiler make types equal
```

can be simplified to

```
int diff = (long) start - (long) stop; // we can substract now
```

is equal to

```
int diff = (long) startMinusStop; // because long - long => long
```

and here we are readable error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int`.

Answer (score 0):

In your first statement you will only cast the variable `start` to an integer. So the result is `int - long` which is a long and does not fit in an integer.

it will be like `int = (int - long)` and java will not allow.